Next.js 14 Not recognizing pages within /app
I am pretty new to Next, and I am trying to help start migrate the /pages directory over to /app to gain full advantage of next 14. However, as I am following the documentation to migrate I am running into issues with attempting to redirect to a page within my app.
currently my app directory is set up very simply like so:
app
|--layout.tsx
|--Test
|  |-- page.tsx

Then going to http://localhost:3000/test it gets /not-found and I get the following browser error:

Watching tutorials online and they seem to seamlessly migrate parts of their /pages over to their /app. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
This is my layout.tsx:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}

any help would be great thanks!

Path should be app/test/page.tsx according to the docs: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/creating-layouts-and-pages#nested-routing

Hi Titus, sorry i made a mistake with my question, it's within /app/test/page.tsx. Im wondering if this could be a config thing?

Just an update on this problem. It seems that my pageExtensions parameter within my next.config.js was the culprit. Unfortunately now my existing /pages routes do not work and only my /app routes work now.
There seems to be something similar (but not really) here:https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48809

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51478
This question thread has helped with this issue

It looks like changing your app routes to conform to the pageExtensions fixes this. I renamed page.tsx to page.m.tsx, which is one of my pageExtensions, and it starts working.
Note that you will have to do this for every special file in the app/ directory. So layout.tsx will also have to become layout.m.tsx, and so on.
